# Перечисление сетевых интерфейсов Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть необходимость получить список активных сетевых интерфейсов Windows. Использую get_if_list(), функция возвращает мне имена ключей реестра (наверное):

```
\Device\NPF_{76FA4D0D-3BFC-47CE-B989-1CA122EA83EE}
\Device\NPF_{C81E7ED9-F086-40F3-BA1E-E7519A40EE39}
```

Выводил на экран этим кодом:

```
for i in get_if_list():
    print(i)
```

Как по этим данным получить нормальное имя сетевого интерфейса?

Comment: Вариант с WinAPI подойдет?

Comment: Да, подойдет любой вариант

Comment: GetAdaptersInfo точно умеет перечислять интерфейсы

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29918755/5741205